# Unit test for angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive

I am trying to write a unit test for a directive, and getting the following error.

> Can't find variable: $compile

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Align number to right
  <br/>
  <mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.7866" scale="1">11.097866</mi-format-number-in-grid>
  <br/>
  <mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.097866"></mi-format-number-in-grid>
  <br/>
  <mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.097866"></mi-format-number-in-grid>
  <br/>
  <mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.097866"></mi-format-number-in-grid>
  <br/>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('miFormatNumberInGrid', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
         var digit = 0;
         var cssClass = "";
         var pctValue = parseFloat(attributes.numbervalue);
         var scale = parseInt(attributes.scale);
         if (attributes.percentchar === "true")
            cssClass = "class='mi-percentsuffix'";
         if (!isNaN(scale))
            digit = scale;
         if (isNaN(pctValue))
            pctValue = 0;
         var containerDOM = angular.element("<span style='" + "float:right;' " + cssClass + ">{{" + pctValue + "|number:" + digit + "}}</span>");
         var compiled = $compile(containerDOM)(scope);
         angular.element(element).replaceWith(compiled);
      }
   };
});


describe('directive: mi-format-number-in-grid', function () {
  // initialize 
  var $compiler,
      $rootScope;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('cgApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
      $compile = $compile;
      $rootScope = $rootScope;
  }));

  it("should have 2 digits after decimal", function () {
      var element = $compile('<mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.97342" scale="2"></mi-format-number-in-grid>')($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
      expect(element.html()).toContain("11.97");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$compile` variable haven't been declared, rather you have declared `$compiler`, you could use `$compiler` for the same.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    $compiler = $compile; //it should be $compiler
    $rootScope = $rootScope;
}));
```

Then do

```
var element = $compiler('<mi-format-number-in-grid numbervalue="11.97342" scale="2"></mi-format-number-in-grid>')($rootScope);
```

---

Rather I'd suggest you to rename `$compiler` to `$compile` and then do change `beforeEach` section dependency injection part like below.

```
// initialize 
var $compile,
    $rootScope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('cgApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_; //it should be $compiler
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. Not getting reference anymore but my test is still failing.

Comment: it("Number should align right", function () {
        var element = '<mi-format-number-in-grid id="testData" numbervalue="11.97342" scale="2" percentchar="true"></mi-format-number-in-grid>';
        element = ngCompile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        var span = element.find('span');
        var floatRight = element.attr('style');
        expect(span).toBeDefined();
        expect(floatRight).toBe("float:right");
    }); 
when I see span in debug mode its empty.

Comment: Could you create plunkr of the same.?

Comment: Here is the pluker for same. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZH7JdkuU35ZQicOUuwFX?p=preview